# Write the following in vector notation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble with expressing an equation in vector form.

The value of $f \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by: $f(i)=x(i)-x(i)^2$

Can we express $f$ in a standard quadratic vector form in $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Depending on the space you work in, consider first to find a basis to this space, and then represent each component of $f$ in this form (column vector). Then simply join those.

Comment: Edited the original